# jQuery dynamically position link-able image icon over draggable image

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Can someone show me how to dynamically overlay an image (an icon in my case) in the upper right hand corner of an image no matter what the size of that image is. It needs to be able to work with the draggable ui so when the image is being moved the overlayed icon stays in its position.

I am rather new to jQuery and I have tried many things but cannot get a working example together. In the end the icon will need to be linkable so I can assign onClick functionality to it.

Can anyone show me some examples or point me in the right direction?

I am using the latest version of jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want the icon to ultimately be clickable, I would avoid my gut intention to use `:after` on a containing element to show the icon. Instead, I would use a simple `div` wrapper with both your draggable image, and an icon inside:

```
<div class="draggable-image">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" />
  <img src="help.png" class="icon" />
</div>
```

Then I would style the container to be `inline-block`, so that it matches the width (and height, for the most part) of its child `img`. This is also a good time to position the icon within the container:

```
.draggable-image {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.draggable-image img.icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
}
```

Now we can bind up the draggable event, referencing the draggable image from within the `ui.helper` object provided to our various draggable methods:

```
$(".draggable-image").draggable({
  stop: function( event, ui ) {
    alert( $("img:first", ui.helper).attr("src") );
  }
});
```

Note I'm access the `:first` image, avoiding our `.icon` image. Lastly, we can bind some click logic to our `.icon` so that we can react to people clicking it:

```
$(".draggable-image .icon").on("click", function(){
  alert( "You've clicked the icon" );
});
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/ihugas/3/edit

Comment: This is good also!. What if the image/div size is dynamic? How would I account for that? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Thanks! This is getting so close. Testing this code I am seeing that the icon isnt in the upper right hand corner. How would I affect the icon's position dynamically?

Comment: @user993514 See my demo again (I've updated the link). The icon is in the top-right. Why do you want to dynamically modify the position of it?

Comment: This is excellent man. Thanks so much. In response to your question. I need the icon to be dynamically positioned based on the image size because I have a grid of images that all vary in size and that are dynamic themselves. How would I do that? This is such a great help!

Comment: @user993514 That's an entirely different question, to be completely honest. The request you  made in  your question here has been satisfied by the answer you received. Please feel free to ask a new question though.

Answer (score 0):

position the icon absolute top left of a containing div (which holds the original 'background' image).  Drag the div using draggable: http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/

Answer (score 0):

Could you not wrap them both in a "position:relative" div and make the div draggable? Then set the z-index of the image to 1 and the icon to 2 so it always sits on top? You can then just use "position:absolute; right:0px; top:0px" on the icon.

So similar to this

http://jsfiddle.net/qJHuf/1/

But the .image div would be an image, and .holder would be the draggable

Comment: This is good. What if the image/div size is dynamic? How would I account for that? Thanks for the help!

Comment: it should work as well, it's the icon that needs the positions. Might just need to play with the styles a bit

Comment: Is there a fancy way to dynamically set the position of the icon based on the height and width of the image?

Comment: you could probably do something using javascript